# How to Query WHERE srdate >= {$currentdate} AND (usr={$uid} or refid={$uid} or refIII={$uid} or refIIII={$uid})

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck this query.

```
select * from mytable WHERE srdate >= {$currentdate} AND (usr={$uid} or refid={$uid} or refIII={$uid} or refIIII={$uid})
```

I need to get current day data. but its getting all data.

Comment: Use `select day` instand of `select *` if this is your question

Comment: What's your exact question about this?

Comment: Hmmm... what does `>=` do?

Answer (score 0):

if you need current day then you should use `=` and not `>=` :

```
WHERE srdate = {$currentdate}
```

as a note, you should use PDO and bindings parameters to prevent SQL injection.